# File reported as missing but it is not

Tags: java, struts, tomcat7

I am working on a java web application using struts that someone else wrote and I was getting errors about an import that was missing in some files so I looked around the project folders and found the file among the jsp files which seemed strange. So, I copied the file into the relevant package and the errors went away. When I went to run the program again on Tomcat I got this error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp(3,55) File "/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" not found
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:41)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:132)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:166)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:410)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:475)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1425)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:239)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:197)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:372)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:352)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:339)
        org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:594)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:344)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

"/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" still exists and hasn't been changed or moved. I decided to delete the file I moved because the program still worked without it but I still get the error and I'm not sure how I could fix this.

Edit:

So I decided to refresh the webpage and a different error showed up:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:168)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:356)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


root cause 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
        java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:132)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:162)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:356)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Comment: Always good to do (new File(filePathString)).exists() to see if Java can really find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your web.xml you need to place taglib definitions right after welcome-page definitions. It worked for me.

Comment: you should paste it which will make it easy for user to understand

Answer (score 3):

The `tld` (tag library) files and their locations are specified in the `web.xml` file.
If you need new `tlds`, the `jsp` files which are using these `tlds` will look first in the `web.xml` to find info and location of the file.

Comment: None of the `tlds` have moved and the `web.xml` points to the correct spots.

Comment: did you manually move any file from its place outside the ide?

Comment: No. I found the java file that seemed to be missing in the WebContent folder with all the JSP files so I right-clicked on it in Eclipse, copied it, and then pasted it in the package it was supposed to be in.